# JasmineJS: alter DOM to create intended value

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, jasmine, sinon

I'm writing unit test for a function that need to get value from DOM to process.

```
getProducts: function() {
  //Create query
  var queryData = {};
  var location = this.$('#location').val();
  var startDate = this.$('#arrival').datepicker('getDate');
  var endDate = this.$('#departure').datepicker('getDate');

  var locationType = this.$('#location option:selected').attr('data-location');
  if (locationType === 'hotel') {
    queryData.hotel = location;
  } else if (locationType === 'city') {
    queryData.city = location;
  }
  queryData.startDate = bookingApp.util.formatDateToData(startDate);
  queryData.endDate = bookingApp.util.formatDateToData(endDate);

  if ((!queryData.hotel && !queryData.city) || !queryData.startDate || !queryData.endDate) {
    return; // I need to get pass this
  }

  //Query to view
  if (this.listView !== null) {
    this.listView.cleanUp();
  }
  bookingApp.summary.reset();
  this.listView = new bookingApp.OrderListView({
    query: queryData
  });
  return false;
},
```

I need to get pass the first **return** statement, but I can't set value for **queryData.city** or **queryData.hotel** as they are local variables:

```
  if ((!queryData.hotel && !queryData.city) || !queryData.startDate || !queryData.endDate) {
    return; // I need to get pass this
  }
```

Are there any way to modify the value of **this.$('#location').val()** so it won't trigger the **return**?

I've tried:

**view.$("#location").val("Newyork");**

**$("#location").val("Newyork");**

But none of them working.

Here my spec:

```
var view;

beforeEach(function () {
  view = new bookingApp.OrderView();
});

it ('getProducts() should create new listView', function() {
  view.$("#location").val("Newyork");
  $("#arrival").val("2017-01-01");
  $("#departure").val("2017-01-03");
  view.getProducts();
  expect(view.listView instanceof bookingApp.OrderListView).toBe(true);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mock the elements the view needs before you run the tests. Right now you trying to set values to element that does not exists.

It should look something like:

```
beforeEach(function () {
  $('div class="my-app"> /* all the required elements here */</div>').appendTo(document.body);
  view = new bookingApp.OrderView({
    el: '.my-app'
  });
});
```

Here `document.body` should be the document of test runner.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what is "document of test runner"?

Comment: The page you see when you are running tests. If you are using a headless browser then the document created by it for running tests.

Comment: I am using phantomJS, do I need to change anything?

Comment: I don't know how phantomjs works. Maybe it works. Else search how to mock elements with phantomjs